# Wordpress Unable to upload images

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-media

For some days now, in the admin area you have had these errors:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'.**

on files *moxie.min.js, plupload.min.js, wp-plupload.min.js*

This does not allow us to upload images to media galleries, pages, articles...

When entering in Media Gallery we have this error: **Uncaught TypeError: wp.Uploader is undefined on media-grid.min.js**; and no images!

If I try to upload an image from a page or post, we have the **same above error** but on the file **media-views.min.js**.

The front-end has no errors.

Some "online solutions" have already been tried, as well as updating everything, restoring a backup, installing worpdress again via ftp...

The problem remains!

I don't know how it happened, the owner of the site didn't make any operation.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The cause of this error is usually simple: the JS file doesn't exist in the referenced location, which causes the host to send a 404 page instead. That page starts with `<!doctype`, and the browser, expecting JavaScript, complains about the `<`. Look through the source code in the browser (Ctrl+U) for the script tag for `moxie.min.js` and click its `src`. You should see the script, and see where the browser is expecting it. Check via FTP if it's actually there.

Comment: The files exist! All files. I've checked them as first stuff! And also overwrite them!
clicking on the src string: it do not open the file, but an html file. But file exist!

Comment: If it opens an html file (which I expected, based on your error), then the link is wrong. The only other explanations is a permissions issue, where the web server can't read the file because it doesn't have read access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!
It was an older redirection. This redirection took all the urls with the term 'upload', so also the js plupload.min.js and consequently all the others (moxie.min.js...).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a cache plugin ? Sometimes using those kind of plugin can break the js for some elements.